# How does symfony2 redirect to requested page after login

Tags: symfony

Say my route **/booking/(.*)** is protected by a firewall configuration in **security.yml** and it requires "**ROLE_USER**", when user tries to access any route that is preceded by "**/booking/**" the app redirects the user to login page for authentication.

So my question is, after user provides his credentials and gets authenticated, how is Symfony 2 able to redirect the user back to the page/route the user had requested for OR where does Symfony 2 store that **route** does it store it in some session or some where else.

***Can we access it and how?***

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is possible and you can access the referring link (that is used if `use_referer` is set to `true`) in the session.

For instance, if you have a `success_handler` service on your `form_login` (in your firewall configuration) that redirects users based on some criteria (commonly roles) but you wanted to redirect the user to the referrer link *if it was set* you could access the referrer link like so:

```
$key = '_security.main.target_path'; #where "main" is your firewall name

//check if the referrer session key has been set 
if ($this->container->get('session')->has($key)) {
    //set the url based on the link they were trying to access before being authenticated
    $url = $this->container->get('session')->get($key);

    //remove the session key
    $this->container->get('session')->remove($key);
}
//if the referrer key was never set, redirect to a default route
else{
    $url = $this->router->generate('member_home');
}

return new RedirectResponse($url);
```

Using the header to get the referrer (ie `$request->headers->get('referer')`) will not work in this case because it will always return the login link.

Thanks to Roman Marintsenko & Ryan Weaver for this [blog](http://knplabs.com/en/blog/redirect-after-registration-in-symfony2)

Comment: Do you have any advice for this case? Here, we do need the referrer of the referrer...

Comment: @aminejallouli you'll probably be best off storing that information somewhere (ie session) and accessing it when you need it.

Comment: You can use the TargetPathTrait then just call the function getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewall_name)

Answer (score 11):

Carrie Kendall's solution worked, thanks!

Here is full implementation in Symfony:

services.yml:

```
login_handler:
    class: Project\BaseBundle\Service\loginHandler
    arguments: ['@router', '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@service_container']
```

and in Project\BaseBundle\Service\loginHandler:

```
namespace Project\BaseBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;


class loginHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface {

    private $router;
    private $container;
    private static $key;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, EntityManager $em, $container) {

        self::$key = '_security.secured_area.target_path';

        $this->router = $router;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->session = $container->get('session');

    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess( Request $request, TokenInterface $token ) {

        $user_entity = $token->getUser();

        if( !$user_entity->getChangePassword() ) {

            $route = $this->router->generate('BaseBundle_home_page');

        } else {

            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Your password must be changed now');

            $route = $this->router->generate('BaseBundle_account_page');

        }

        //check if the referer session key has been set
        if ($this->session->has( self::$key )) {

            //set the url based on the link they were trying to access before being authenticated
            $route = $this->session->get( self::$key );

            //remove the session key
            $this->session->remove( self::$key );
            //if the referer key was never set, redirect to a default route

        } else{

            $url = $this->generateUrl('BaseBundle_home_page');

            return new RedirectResponse($route);

        }

        return new RedirectResponse($route);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too. I used security.yml and in the registration action used:

```
$redirectUrl = $request->getSession()->get('_security.account.target_path');
```

enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

Symfony uses the [HTTP Referer header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) to redirect a user back to the page they came from .. ie the referrer

You can set this using the security configuration `use_referer: true` in the security.yml, [details here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#redirecting-after-login)

You can access the referer header from a controller using using the following :

```
$referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
```

**Note** the header is miss-spelt, its referer (one r)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I require is a bit different. After a little searching I found the answer to my question http://knplabs.com/blog/redirect-after-registration-in-symfony2