# AuthenticationSuccessHandler, redirect after login and referrer

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I've just added with this forum's help an AuthenticationSuccessHandler which implements on my site a redirection when the user login via fosuserbundle or fosfacebookbundle. The redirection changes when the user has the profile completed or not, and if it has it completed, I want them to be redirected where they were previously, this is why I am using the referrer variable.

```
    namespace Me\MyBundle\Handler;
    
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    
    
    class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    
        protected $router;
    
        public function __construct( HttpUtils $httpUtils, array $options, $router) {
        $this->router = $router;
            parent::__construct( $httpUtils, $options );
        }
    
        public function onAuthenticationSuccess( Request $request, TokenInterface $token ) {
            
        $user = $token->getUser();
        
        if($user->getProfileComplete()!=1){
    //redirects to profile editing
            $url = 'fos_user_profile_edit';
        }else{
            $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
            if($referer == NULL){
    //redirects to custom url if there is not any referer
                $url = 'My_customurl';
            }else{
    //redirects to the referer
                $url = $referer;
            }
        }
    
        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate($url));
        }
    }
```

my security.yml note that I have the use_referrer declared in both fos_facebook and form_login:

```
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            fos_facebook:
              app_url: "http://apps.facebook.com/app"
              server_url: "http://www.app.com"
              login_path: /user/login
              check_path: /facebook/login_check
              provider: fos_facebook_provider
              success_handler: my_auth_success_handler
              use_referer: true
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                login_path: /user/login
                check_path: /user/login_check
                use_forward: false
                success_handler: my_auth_success_handler
                use_referer: true
                failure_path: null
            logout:
                path: /user/logout
            anonymous: ~
            remember_me:
                  key:      mySuperKey
                  lifetime: 4147200
                  path:     /
                  domain:   ~
```

When I login and I don't have my profile completed, I am getting redirected successfully but when it is completed and referrer is not null I am having 500 errors:

When I login with Facebook I get an 500 error: "Unable to generate a URL for the named route "http://app.com/app_dev.php/user/login" as such route does not exist." and the url in firefox is this: "http://app.com/app_dev.php/facebook/login_check"

And when I login with the form, I get a 500 error: "Unable to generate a URL for the named route "http://app.com/app_dev.php/user/login" as such route does not exist." and the url in firefox is this: "http://app.com/app_dev.php/user/login_check"

Any ideas, I am getting crazy. I thing its because the referral has stored user/login and when it go to login_check goes to user/login again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying generate route using actual url, not route name. Try this code:

```
if ($user->getProfileComplete() != 1) {
    $url = $this->router->generate('fos_user_profile_edit');
} else {
    $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
    if ($referer == NULL) {
        $url = $this->router->generate('My_customurl');
    } else {
        $url = $referer;
    }
}

return new RedirectResponse($url);
```

Comment: Yeahh!!! It's working, but it is redirecting me to the login page once authenticated (user/login) instead the previous one. I think it's because in the referer variable is set the login (wich is the last i've visited) Is there any way to fix this? Thanks :-) :-) :-)

Comment: Try `$referer = $request->getSession()->get('_security.'.$this->providerKey.'.target_path', null);`

Comment: Is getting null because is redirecting me to My_customurl i've been seeing this post but i am unable to get it working:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079592/how-does-symfony2-redirect-to-requested-page-after-login

Comment: Any ideas please? anyone?