# Symfony 3: Redirect to Login with Referer

Tags: symfony, http-referer

I had this on my `security.yml` under `access_control`:

`- { path: ^/somepath/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, requires_channel: https}`

Whenever I try to go to `/somepath/someotherpath` manually using the browser's address bar, it will redirect me to login page. The problem is the `$request->server->get('HTTP_REFERER')` is null.

Am I doing something wrong or is it just that manually typing the secured url will not have an HTTP_REFERER?

Comment: what has the referer got to do with it?  Are you sure youre actually authenticated?

Comment: I am sure I am authenticated. I need to get the `HTTP_REFERER` to redirect the app manually. But it's always empty. The `HTTP_REFERER` is showing if we redirect using `location.href` from javscript, but the scenario I need to cover is from manually typing the url.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079592/how-does-symfony2-redirect-to-requested-page-after-login

Comment: Are you redirected to `/somepath/someotherpath` after you logged in?

Comment: maybe ive not had enough coffee.  From your question it looked like you were getting redirected to login when you didnt expect to. Hence not being logged in was the issue.  Very confusing question.

Comment: The logging in is not the problem. The problem is, when I try to go to a secured URL (`/somepath/someotherpath`) while not authorized, it will redirect me to the login, This is expected. But, since I'm from `/somepath/someotherpath` and redirected to login page, I expect my `HTTP_REFERER` will not be empty. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Wikpiedia:

> When visiting a webpage, the referrer or referring page is the URL of the previous webpage from which a link was followed.

If you type the url manually you didn't follow any link on any previous page so there is no referer.

Comment: My problem is I expect to have `HTTP_REFERER` since I am unauthorized and redirected from secured URL (`/somepath/someotherpath`) to login page. I am expecting that my `HTTP_REFERER` will be `/somepath/someotherpath`.